# Node js : read two files , compare parts of files and output a sorted file

Tags: node.js

I just started node.js and tried to solve the below problem.
I used  fs.readfile and async module. but it is not working properly.
Anyone could show me a sample code?
Thank you in advance

Ex) Read two big files at same time and sort them together by time.
 Should come up with an output file like below

```
file A :

<time=100> james
<time=210> jordan
<time=300> cam
<time=500> joly
<time=700> car
..... 
 //this is a big file,  we need to handle a buffer properly

file B :

<time=90> sam
<time=210> foo
<time=350> call
<time=600> seattle
<time=660> usa
..... 
 //this is a big file, we  need to handle a buffer properly

output file :

<time=90> sam
<time=100> james
<time=210> jordan
<time=210> foo
<time=300> cam
<time=350> call
<time=500> joly
<time=600> seattle
<time=660> usa
<time=700> car
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require('bluebird');


var readFileAsync = function (filePath) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(data);
        });

    });
};

var mergeFileData = function () {
    return Promise.join(
        readFileAsync('fileA'),
        readFileAsync('fileB'),
        function (dataA, dataB) {
            return mergeAndSortData(dataA, dataB)
        });

};
```

You should declare the `mergeAndSortData` function for yourself.